# docker-compose up "ERROR: Error processing tar file(archive/tar: invalid tar header)

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I am unable to run `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose build --no-cache`. Both exit with `ERROR: Error processing tar file(archive/tar: invalid tar header)`.

I got myself into this situation by running

To stop and remove the containers:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

To delete all the images:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

I've tried the following:

- `docker-compose ps` doesn't list any containers or images.
- `docker ps -a` doesn't list any containers either.
- `docker image list` doesn't list any images.

I am running `dockerd` in debug mode and I'm seeing:

```
DEBU[0998] Calling GET /v1.22/images/codesource_buildbot/json 
ERRO[0998] Handler for GET /v1.22/images/codesource_buildbot/json returned error: No such image: codesource_buildbot
```

So it seems as though as I've managed to get docker into a strange state and can't get it back to a working state.

I've tried `docker-compose down` and that hasn't helped either.

**Docker Version**:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:14:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:14:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

**docker-compose version: docker-compose version 1.12.0, build b31ff33**

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  buildbot:
    build: ./containers/buildbot
    ports: 
      - "8010:8010"
    volumes:
      - "./containers/buildbot/volume:/code"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:latest
WORKDIR /home
RUN ["apt-get", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "python-dev"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "python-pip"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "git-all"]
RUN ["pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pip"]
RUN ["pip", "install", "--ignore-installed", "six"]
RUN ["pip", "install", "service_identity"]
RUN ["pip", "install", "buildbot[bundle]"]
CMD bash wait_for_master.sh
```

Comment: Please include the full output from `docker version`. How large is your build directory (size of all the files in the directory and sub directories)?

Comment: @BMitch I updated the docker version with the complete information above. The full size of the directory I'm working in is 472K.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, but you may want to include your Dockerfile that you're trying to build and docker-compose.yml file that can reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The error message states that the `codesource_buildbot` image doesn't exist.  You have to rebuild it or add a proper `build` directive to your docker-compose.yml

EDIT:

PD: Your Dockerfile is a bit too convoluted.  You could use:

`FROM debian:latest
WORKDIR /home
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python-dev \
    python-pip \
    git-all && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --ignore-installed six && \
    pip install service_identity && \
    pip install buildbot[bundle]
CMD bash wait_for_master.sh`

I would add `--no-cache-dir` to the `pip` commands so the Zip files are not cached and the image is smaller.

Comment: I have a build directive in that file. I added the files above.

Comment: I see you're using the current directory `.` in the YAML file.  Are you running docker-compose in the correct directory?  What is the output of `ls`?

Comment: `docker-compose.yml

    containers:
    buildbot

    tools:
    delete-all-containers.sh  delete-all-image`

Comment: Add `image: codesource_buildbot` just before the `build:` directive in the YAML.

Comment: **docker-compose up --build** still says **ERROR: Error processing tar file(archive/tar: invalid tar header):**

Comment: Try a manual `docker build -t codesource_buildbot -f containers/buildbot/Dockerfile .` to see any error messages.

Comment: I tried running the dockerfile with `docker build` and then I tagged it as `codesource_buildbot` and then `docker-compose up `worked. But then I tried `docker-compose up --build` returns the same error `ERROR: Error processing tar file(archive/tar: invalid tar header):`. So basically, it won't create the image on it's own.

Comment: Now we're seeing progress and that's a good thing.  Don't use `--build`.  Use `up -d` (for *daemon) and it should build on its own.  Which version of Docker Compose are you using?

Comment: PD: I don't see `--build` as a valid option to docker-compose.  Just the `build` command in Docker Compose 1.10.1 & 1.13.0

Comment: I'll give that a shot. `docker-compose up` has a valid `--build` option. https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/. I'm using docker-compose 1.12.0.

Comment: I deleted the image I created manually and then ran `docker-compose up -d` and I'm still getting the `ERROR: Error processing tar file(archive/tar: invalid tar header):`

Comment: Ahhhhh I think I was. ls -l showed that one of the folders created by the container in the shared volume was owned by root user and root group. I used chown and chgrp to change the user and group and `docker-compose up --build` started working. So I think what I need to do is to get that folder created somewhere else in the container and not in the shared volume.

Comment: Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Over a similar experience I had on the very same problem I just removed all the folders I had mounted as volumes. It happened over a Ubuntu GNU/Linux running machine.

For example if I had the following `docker-compose.yml` (taken from a personal project):

```
version: '2'
services:

 phpBB_dev:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    args:
      XDEBUG_HOST: 172.17.0.1
      XDEBUG_PORT: 9021
      UID: 1000
      GID: 1000
  image: 'pcmagas/phpbb_dev'
  links:
    - mariadb
    - postgresql
  volumes:
    - "$SRC_PATH:/var/www/html:Z"
    - "$SRC_PATH_3_1_10:/var/www/phpBB_3_1_10:Z"
    - "$SRC_PATH_3_0_14:/var/www/phpBB_3_0_14:Z"

 nginx:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - "5092:5092"
    - "5093:5093"
    - "5094:5094"
  links:
    - "phpBB_dev"
  volumes:
    - './nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro'
    - './logs/dev/nginx:/var/logs'
  volumes_from:
    - 'phpBB_dev'

 mariadb:
  image: mariadb
  volumes:
    - './db/maria:/var/lib/mysql'
  ports:
    - '5434:5432'
  environment:
    MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
    MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD: "yes"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: 'phpBB'
    MYSQL_USER: 'phpbb'
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'a_dummy_passwd'

 postgresql:
  image: postgres
  volumes:
    - './db/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
  ports:
    - '3306:3306'
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: 'phpbb'
    POSTGRES_USER: 'phpbb'
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'a_dummy_passwd'
```

I would remove the folders `./db` where the mariadb and the postgresql stored the data. Also I would remove the `./logs` where the nginx keeps its logs.

A good rule of thumb (for GNU/Linux or similar) is to follow theese steps:

**Step1:**

List all files & folders mounted as VOLUME and have owner root and group with `ls -l` command

**Step2:**

Then remove them with the `rm -rf command`